# Image Resize & Crop

Tags: php, codeigniter, resize, crop

I want to resize a image such that the resize always fills the required area.  I want the script to take any size image, resize the shortest side to 90px, then crop off the top and bottom (or left and right side if it's landscape) as to get a square 90px by 90px

Comment: could you show what you have tried ?

Comment: I used the Codeigniter Image_lib to resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does it with the GD functions.

The source image can be in JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP format. If you know the format beforehand you can get rid of the switch statement. The result is saved as JPEG.

```
                    $srcPath = "your source image path goes here";
                    $dstPath = "your destination image path goes here";
                    $size = "90x90";

                    list($w, $h, $type) = getimagesize($srcPath);

                    switch ($type) {
                            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcPath);
                                    break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                                    $src = imagecreatefrompng($srcPath);
                                    break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($srcPath);
                                    break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_BMP:
                                    $src = imagecreatefrombmp($srcPath);
                                    break;
                    }

                    list($dst_w, $dst_h) = explode('x', $size);
                    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);

                    $dst_x = $dst_y = 0;
                    $src_x = $src_y = 0;

                    if ($dst_w/$dst_h < $w/$h) {
                            $src_w = $h*($dst_w/$dst_h);
                            $src_h = $h;
                            $src_x = ($w-$src_w)/2;
                            $src_y = 0;
                    } else {
                            $src_w = $w;
                            $src_h = $w*($dst_h/$dst_w);
                            $src_x = 0;
                            $src_y = ($h-$src_h)/2;
                    }

                    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);

                    imagejpeg($dst, $dstPath);
                    imagedestroy($src);
                    imagedestroy($dst);
```

Comment: it is creating a black image 90*90

Comment: Although this is perfectly valid, it's a pretty inefficient way to do it with CodeIgniter, which has its own library for this task.